# Why is the least upper bound of a set adherent to the set?

Tags: real-analysis

My textbook claims that:

> The least upper bound of a (non-empty) set S is adherent to S.

The definition of **adherent**:

Let $S$ be a set of numbers. Let $a$ be a number. We shall say that $a$ is
adherent to $S$ if given $\epsilon$ there exists an element $x \in S$ such that $|x - a| < \epsilon$

---

Why isn't the following set a counterexample to this statement?

The set containing members of $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ for $n = 1,2,3...$.

In this example, $1$ is the $sup$. Yet, we can't get arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: 1 is element of the set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One characterization of the supremum is given as: $a=\sup S$ iff $a$ is an upper bound for $S$, and for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $x\in S$ such that $a-\epsilon < x \le a$.

It is easy to see that $a-\epsilon < x\le a$ implies $|x-a|<\epsilon$. So, $a$ is supremum $\Rightarrow$ $a$ is adherent.

In the example you gave, for any given $\epsilon>0$, you can choose $x=a=\sup S=1$. The definition doesn't restrict you in that sense.

Comment: To sum up, you don't need to find distinct points arbitrarily close to the $\sup S$. This would be much more stronger than what the definition/characterization requires.

Comment: @ClementC. is right. I edited my post. Sorry and thanks.